# How to use AdDuplex inside HubControl?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I am trying to use AdDuplex control inside a Hub Control in a Windows 8.1 Store app (C#). The control seems to work perfectly fine until the number of sections increase such that it needs scrolling. As soon as having scrolls, I start getting message that the Ad control is not completely visible (when I set the IsTest property to true).

For testing the issue I created an empty page, added a Hub control with some sections. In each section I put only one AdDuplex Control. When the number of section is very few that it does not need scrolling, it works just fine. But if I add a few more sections such that the Hub control starts scrolling then I get this message: "Some element is covering AdDuplex ad control. Make sure the control is fully visible and is not hidden by other elements or animations."

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Only in the separate section of the page grid/stackpanel. You can't make some part of HubControl always visible. As additional profit, users will get more space at the page in the paid version of the app (where no advertising).